# More efficient way of using foreach?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I'm using a php foreach loop to pull data from  database to generate a header but as I know there is only one result there must be a more efficient way?

```
<?php
foreach ($category as $value)
{
    echo "<header style='background-color:#".$value->CategoryColor."'>";
        echo "<div class='container'>";
            echo "<div class='row'>";
                echo "<div class='col-lg-12'>";
                    echo "<div class='page-intro'>";
                        echo "<span class='title'><i class='fa ".$value->CategoryIcon."'></i> ".$value->CategoryTitle."</span>";
                        echo "<span class='descriptive'>".$value->CategoryDescription."</span>";
    }
?>
```

This is using CodeIgniter MVC

Comment: Is `$category` always going to have only one result? Can you access the value with `$category[0]`?

Comment: If you know there is only one result simply don't use foreach in this case..

Comment: Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I get this error when trying to echo the variable in that way.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how i can echo the variables without the need for a foreach, any other method I try results in some form of error.

Comment: What's the `var_dump($category)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach ($category->result() as $value):  ?>

<header style="background-color:#<?= $value->CategoryColor; ?>">
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-lg-12'>
<div class='page-intro'>
<span class='title'><i class='fa <?= $value->CategoryIcon; ?>'></i> <?= $value->CategoryTitle; ?></span>
<span class='descriptive'><?= $value->CategoryDescription; ?></span>
}     
<?php      endforeach;?>
?>
```